# Configuration Checker

Tags: symfony

in my configuration i have this erreur

```
Add "phar" to suhosin.executor.include.whitelist in php.ini*.
```

i done my php init in my server sbs.tn but his not function

my php.ini :

```
 disable_functions = allow_url_fopen, escapeshellarg, escapeshellcmd, ini_alter, passthru, parse_ini_file, popen, proc_open, proc_close, proc_terminate, proc_get_status, proc_nice, readfile, show_source, system

extension_dir = "/sbctn/lib/php5"
date.timezone = Africa/Tunis
                extension=php_pdo.dll
                extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
                extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
                extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
                extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
                extension=php_pdo_oci8.dll
                extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
                extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
                extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the php5-suhosin package?

```
sudo apt-get install php5-suhosin
```

Add this line to php.ini:

```
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist="phar"
```

Comment: sudo hi's is'nt identified in my dos

Comment: yes  but hi is not identified in my server hi watch me last erreur